# How to extract letter words only from an arbitrary input file

Tags: java, delimiter

I'm writing a spell checker, and I have to extract only word (constructed out of letter). I'm having trouble using multiple delimiters. Java documentation specifies the use of several delimiters, but I have troubles including every printing character that is not a letter.

```
in_file.useDelimiter("., !?/@#$%^&*(){}[]<>\\\"'");
```

in this case - run time

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
 Unclosed character class near index 35
```

I tried using pattern such as

```
("\s+,|\s+\?|""|\s:|\s;|\{}|\s[|[]|\s!");
```

run time -

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
 Illegal repetition
```

I'm aware of tokenizer but we are restricted to use scanner.

Comment: Um, the `""` inside your second string does not look too good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Metacharacter for word-extraction: `\w`. It selects everything that is considered to be a word.

If you are just interested in word *boundarys* you can use `\b`, which should be appropriate as a delimiter.

See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html (Chapter 3.2)

Comment: \w matches numbers and underscores as well

Answer (score 2):

The pattern in `Scanner` is supposed to be a regular expression that describes all the characters you don't want included in a token, repeated one or more times (this last part is because the word may be delimited by more than one space/punctuation etc.)

This means you need a pattern that describes something which is not a letter. Regular expressions give you the ability to *negate* a class of characters. So if a letter is `[a-zA-Z]`, a "non-letter" is `[^a-zA-Z]`. So you can use `[^a-zA-Z]+` to describe "1 or more non-letters".

There are other ways to express the same thing. `\p{Alpha}` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. And you negate it by capitalizing the P: `\P{Alpha}+`.

If your file contains words that are not in English, then you may want to use a Unicode category: `\P{L}+` (meaning: 1 or more characters which are not Unicode letters).

Demonstration:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner( "Hello, 123 שלום 134098ho こんにちは 'naïve,. 漢字     +?+?+مرحبا.");
sc.useDelimiter("\\P{Alpha}+");
while ( sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
ho
na
ve
```

This is because we asked for just US-ASCII alphabet (`\p{Alpha}`). So it broke the word `naïve` because ï is not a letter in the US-ASCII range. It also ignored all those words in other languages. But if we use:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner( "Hello, 123 שלום 134098ho こんにちは 'naïve,. 漢字     +?+?+مرحبا.");
sc.useDelimiter("\\P{L}+");
while ( sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Then we have used a unicode category, and the output will be:

```
Hello
שלום
ho
こんにちは
naïve
漢字
مرحبا
```

Which gives you all the words in all the languages. So it's your choice.

**Summary**

To create a `Scanner` delimiter that allows you to get all the strings that are made of a particular category of characters (in this case, letters):

- Create a regular expression for the category of characters you *want*
- Negate it
- Add `+` to signify 1 or more of the negated category.

This is just a common recipe, and complicated cases may require a different method.